# one of the column in the gridview has same result

Tags: c#, datagridview, exchangewebservices

im working to display the result on the gridview and one of the the result on the column has the same value but on the console it display all of the result and here's my code

```
    private bool DisplayErrorEmails(ExchangeService service)
    {
        try
        {


            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
            DateTime TwoDays = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);

            //Search for the Undelivered Email
            SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection compoundFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or);
compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR"));
            compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.DR"));
            compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.DELAYED"));
            compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.IPNRN"));
            compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.IPNNRN"));
            compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.SMIME.NDR"));
            compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.SMIME.DR"));
            compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.NoteSMIME.MULTIPARTSIGNED.NDR"));
            compoundFilter.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "REPORT.IPM.Note.SMIME.MULTIPARTSIGNED.DR"));



            //Displays the result
            ItemView view = new ItemView(100);

            do
            {
                findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, compoundFilter, view);
                foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
                {

                    if (findResults.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        EmailList.Add(item);
                        item.Load();

                        string Sender = item.DisplayTo;
                        string Subject = item.Subject;
                        string DateCreated = item.DateTimeCreated.ToString();

                        //Display the EmailBody
                        PropertySet itemProperty = new PropertySet();
                        itemProperty.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
                        itemProperty.Add(ItemSchema.Body);
                        PropertySet FindItemPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
                        view.PropertySet = FindItemPropertySet;
                        PropertySet GetItemsPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
                        GetItemsPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
                        if (findResults.Items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults.Items, GetItemsPropertySet);
                            foreach (Item Item in findResults.Items)
                            {
                                var EmailBody = Item.Body.Text;
                                var pattern = new[] { "Remote Server returned '554 5.4.4 SMTPSEND.DNS.NonExistentDomain; nonexistent domain",
                    "Either there are no alternate hosts, or delivery failed to all alternate hosts",
                    "Remote Server returned '550 No Such User Here",
                    "5.2.3 smtp;550 5.2.3 RESOLVER.RST.SendSizeLimit.Org; message too large for this organization",
                    "5.1.10 smtp;550 5.1.10 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipientNotFound; Recipient user@contoso.com not found by SMTP address lookup",
                    "Remote Server returned '550 4.4.7 QUEUE.Expired; message expired'",
                    "Remote host said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist",};


                                string matchingMessage = String.Empty;
                                var found = pattern.Any(m => { var match = EmailBody.Contains(m);
                                    if (match) matchingMessage = m;
                                    return match;

                                });
                                matchingMessagePublic = matchingMessage;
                                Console.WriteLine("Subject" + item.Subject);
                              Console.WriteLine("Error::::" + matchingMessage);

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                if (findResults.NextPageOffset != null)
                {
                    view.Offset = (int)findResults.NextPageOffset;
                }

            }
            while (findResults.MoreAvailable);

            Status = "list of undelivered email.";
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and here's my code to display the result on the gridview

```
public void LoadResult()
    {

        EmailMethods email = new EmailMethods();

        email.EmailServer = "https://SampleExchange.asmx";
        email.AccountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Account"];
        email.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret"];
        email.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
        email.GetEmails();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Sender", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("DateCreated", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("EmailHeader", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ErrorTwo", typeof(string));

        foreach (Item item in email.EmailList)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.Subject, item.DisplayTo, item.DateTimeCreated, item.Body, email.matchingMessagePublic);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

on the email.matchMakingPublic that is the column has the same result. can i add the matchmaking on the item? or on the microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item so that the it will display the correct result on the gridview  because i try to debug the loop on the email.matchmakingpublic just like rotating on the same result. can anyone help me with my code thanks.

Comment: Gridview1.DataSource = dt; and GridView1.DataBind(); should be outside of the foreach loop

Comment: i tried to move the  
Gridview1.DataSource = dt; and GridView1.DataBind(); outside the loop and still i get the same result on the email.matchingMessagePublic how can i to become item.matchingMessagePublic like this? the i set the matchingMessagePublic as public string.